# What does iisreset command do in backend

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, iis

I am curious to know what the `iisreset` command does and executes in the back end.

Is there any service which is stopped and started again or is it something related to worker process?

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

IISReset stops and restarts the entire web server (including non-ASP.NET apps). That includes the following services: **IISADMIN**, World Wide Web Publishing Service (**W3SVC**) and Windows Process Activation Service (**WAS**).

When you do an iisreset, IIS will create a new process to serve requests. All sessions connected to your Web server (including Internet, FTP, SMTP, and NNTP) will be dropped. Any data held in Web applications will be lost. All Internet sites will be unavailable. Then it will try to move all requests on to the new process. After a timeout the old process will be killed automatically.

There are recommendations to restart your web sites in an alternative way by recycling worker processes. More information [HERE](https://fullsocrates.wordpress.com/2012/07/25/iisreset-vs-recycling-application-pools/)

Comment: Moved to a comment against the question - @paul-strupeikis please feel free to expand with original content here so we can undelete your answer. Thanks.